# angularjs x editable controls lose focus after done or cancel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable, onsubmit, onblur

I have basic x-editable controls such as input fields or select. I just wish to retain focus after I am done with the control.

`template:`

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" e-onblur="console.log(this);">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
    </div>
```

`controller:`

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
   $scope.user = {id: 1, name: 'name1'};
});
```

Please see a live version of the problem:
`http://plnkr.co/edit/BjWwXIlYyyLvRnVwO8m8?p=preview`

I added a blur function but i cant seem to modify it correctly to do so. If there are other solutions, i would like to know.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit?  What do you mean by 'after i'm done with the control'?  What are you trying to do after you are done with the control?

Comment: when i press `enter` it should finish editing but not focus out to the 1st thing on the page, it should stay on the control so i could press `enter` again (if i wanted) and restart editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@heyNow, the outline of the solution is this:

1. Create a non-isolate 'focus' directive and apply it to the link element.  This should take a boolean, where true sets the focus
2. Create an onhide function that makes the condition in the 'focus' directive true
3. create an 'unsetFocus' function which sets the 'focus' condition to false and should be called with ng-blur and onshow.

here is the html

```
 <a href="#" onhide="onhide(user)" onshow="unsetFocus()" 
        ng-blur="unsetFocus()" focus="focusObj==user" 
        editable-text="user.name">
        {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
 </a>
```

and the directive and controller:

```
app.directive('focus', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.focus, function(newval,oldval) {
        if (newval) { 
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus(); 
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user',
    status: 2
  };
  $scope.onhide = function(obj) {
    $scope.focusObj = obj;
  }
  $scope.unsetFocus = function() {
    $scope.focusObj = null;
  }
}
```

check out [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Fvuks?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! this works! I renamed the directive as `myFocus` and added it as an attribute to the `<a href ..>` as i didn't want it to interfere with any other non x-editable control. That seems to work as well. 
Hope they add this to the library so that we don't have to come up with these workarounds